# R read csv with association rules not as datafram, but arules class

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I have created set of association rules in Julia language, and saved them as csv. Now I would like to use R to make visualizations of them, but when I read csv it is a data frame, not a arules class (which is kind of obvious!).

**How to convert data frame into rules-class** (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/arules/versions/1.6-6/topics/rules-class) to use visualizations from `arulesViz` library (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesViz/vignettes/arulesViz.pdf)?

```
# reproduce some data
dat <- data.frame(
   lhs_ids   = c("{}", "{B}"), 
   rhs_id    = c("{A}", "{A}"), 
   confidence = c(0.25, 0.2),
   support = c(0.25, 0.03),
   lift = c(1, 0.5),
   )
# convert
a_rules <- as(dat, "rules")

Error in as(., "rules") : 
  no method or default for coercing “data.frame” to “rules”
```

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of the rules in the format that you have stored them in your csv?

Answer (score 0):

You should use PMML, the standard way to transfer rules between tools. See: https://rdrr.io/cran/arules/man/pmml.html